# Writing JSON in HTML

Tags: jquery, json, api, weather

I am brand new to actually using an API, getting the JSON data and throwing it in to an actually HTML file and making the results look pretty.

I am good with HTML/CSS/jQuery. But not this in depth with jQuery it seems (I can do the basics)

This is an example of the JSON data I am getting back from Weather Underground's API

```
    "current_observation": {
    "image": {
    "url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
    "title":"Weather Underground",
    "link":"http://www.wunderground.com"
    },
    "display_location": {
    "full":"Bowling Green, KY",
    "city":"Bowling Green",
    "state":"KY",
    "state_name":"Kentucky",
    "country":"US",
    "country_iso3166":"US",
    "zip":"42101",
    "latitude":"37.02899933",
    "longitude":"-86.46366119",
    "elevation":"154.00000000"
    }
```

I can see from this that `display_location` is inside of `current_observation`.

I want to pull out and display `full` as an h1 on my website (I actually want to do more info, but I feel like after I get this down I can handle the rest.)

So here is what I have currently:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="area"></section>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function(){ 
            $.getJSON("http://api.wunderground.com/api/[MY API KEY]/conditions/q/autoip.json",
            function(data){
                $.each(data){
                    content = '<h1>' + json.current_observation.display_location.full + '</h1>';
                    $(content).appendTo("#area");
                 });
              });
           });
    </script>
</html>
```

It does not work :-/

Any help is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this:

```
content = '<h1>' + json.current_observation.display_location.full + '</h1>';
```

What does `json` refer to ?? Also `$.each(data){` is invalid syntax. See [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). Your `each` loop should probably look like

```
$.each(data, function(i, json) {
    content = '<h1>' + json.current_observation.display_location.full + '</h1>';
    $(content).appendTo("#area");
});
```

which will work if the `data` returned is an array of objects like that which is included in the question. You should `console.log(data)` to see its form.. you may be able to eliminate the `each` loop and just use

```
content = '<h1>' + data.current_observation.display_location.full + '</h1>';
```

Comment: Thank you. I also was missing something on the end of the URL but this helped. Thanks tons! Tried to up vote but not high enough rep.

Comment: @Clay_Cauley glad to help, just +1 when you get the chance

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be an useless parenthesis. Try :

```
$().ready(function(){ 
        $.getJSON("http://api.wunderground.com/api/[MY API KEY]/conditions/q/autoip.json",
        function(data){
            $.each(data){
                content = '<h1>' + json.current_observation.display_location.full + '</h1>';
                $(content).appendTo("#area");
             } // Change here
          });
       });
```

Comment: This is incorrect. It will result in `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

Comment: You're right. The `);` was correct, it was a missing `function(i, json)` as second parameter. Sorry about that.